# Google Sheets Syntax Questions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets:

In Column B I would like to display only the values from column A that meet the criteria of containing the text "this text," if a range is needed for a sample, let's say A1:A10.

In column A of TABNAME1 I would like to display the values from Column C located in a different tab, TABNAME2.

I searched around a bit and couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: For the first question, this works, but perhaps it could be cleaned up.  I stick this in column B and I get only the values containing the specified text.

=QUERY(A1:A10 , "Select A Where A contains 'this text' ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### for B column:

```
=QUERY(A1:A10, "where A contains 'this text'", 0)
```

or:

```
=FILTER(A1:A10, REGEXMATCH(A1:A10, "this text"))
```

#### for column A:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TABNAME2!C1:C10)
```

or:

```
={TABNAME2!C1:C10}
```